# SQL Server 2008 delete query error

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I am new to SQL. I am learning through installing SQL SERVER Manangement Studio 2008 on my Laptop.

I wanted to delete dulplicate records. Henceforth, I have written below query:

```
DELETE from emp A WHERE ROWID < (SELECT max(rowid) FROM emp B WHERE A.id = B.id);
```

and getting below error

> Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25501 DELETE from emp A WHERE
>   ROWID < (SELECT max(rowid) FROM emp B WHERE A.id = B.id) There was an
>   error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset =
>   17,Token in error = A ]

Kindly help!

Comment: try to use full syntax like `delete from [emp] as [a]...`

Comment: That error message looks like SQL Server Compact edition? You will be better off installing the free SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 1):

`ROWID` only exists in Oracle, it has no exact correspondence in SQL server, so you'll need to rewrite the query without it. If you don't have a foreign key, a common table expression to generate a synthetic row number may be the easiest;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) rownum
  FROM emp
)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE rownum<>1;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c9e1/1).

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id...)` will number each row with the same ID with a unique number, the first row gets 1, the next 2 etc. The outer query just deletes all except the row numbered 1.